# Using socat, how to send to and receive from a public DNS server?

Tags: socat, dig

In a file called "query.bin" we have stored the data that is transmitted to a public DNS server by the following command.

```
dig +notcp hello.com @8.8.8.8
```

How can query.bin now be sent to 8.8.8.8 again and the reply stored in a file called "reply.bin", using socat throughout?

Eventually reply.bin will be sent back to the DNS client that initiated the query, eg dig above. But first, file query.bin will be manually inspected before the ok is given to pass it on to 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how it can be done:

```
cat query.bin | socat -x - UDP:8.8.8.8:53 > result.bin
```